# What does the phrase "hop across an icy chasm" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

I came across the phrase "hop across an icy chasm" in the following sentence from the description (not available online) of an app:

*All you need to do is to tap to **hop across an icy chasm**.*

Does the said phrase mean "to jump from one part of the chasm to another"?

I know the lexical meaning of the word "hop" is "to jump". But I am not sure about the meaning of the word "across" here.

Comment: What are these "rinses"? Maybe it's about hopping *from one **part of** the rinse to another part*, or maybe it's about hopping *from **one rinse** to another*. But surely that should be obvious from the ***context*** (which you haven't provided).

Comment: an app that does what exactly?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Unfortunately, there is a lack of enough context in the text.

Comment: @Lambie It's a game app.

Comment: Google found precisely ***one*** match for the string ["tap to hop across"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tap+to+hop+across%22&oq=%22tap+to+hop+across%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.355040j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but I can't find any useful matches for "icy rinses". Without context, this question is going nowhere. But even *with* context, it's irrelevant to the process of learning English, since few if any native speakers will have any idea what this is all about.

Comment: Even if I didn't get any definitive answer, I find your comments very helpful. It is always helpful to get the opinion of English experts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now I know that I was right in thinking that the word across is ambiguous here. Thank you for confirming this.

Comment: What kind of game? What is the object of the game. No, hop is not ambiguous in hop across. **You hop across a puddle**, but I do not understand: hop across a rinse. A rinse is flush with water. The issue is icy rinse.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry for the confusion. Please see the edited question. I guess there is no ambiguity now.

Comment: Now your quote mentions a chasm, but your question still asks about a "rinse", so it's even more unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you for pointing this out. Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A chasm is a very deep crack or break in the ground (which in this case is presumably actually ice).

Hopping across a chasm means to hop from one side of the chasm to the other.

Having to jump across a chasm when crossing an ice field is a common trope in action movies set in the arctic.